# Laravel Stuck when There's Process in Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I created a web project using the laravel framework. In my web, there's a form that can be filled by user. When user click submit button, a controller will be called by POST method. The controller will run some batch file (on windows) to get output for the  result view. Below is how i run the batch file:

exec(*path to bat*);

The process run in the controller can take about six minutes. But somehow when there's a process running on the controller, other users can't access the web, even the login page. So when we press login it will continue to load until the process in the controller is complete, then the login page will open.

The way I run the project is with the *php artisan serve*. Does anyone know why this could happen? I want the web to be able to run multiple processes at the same time. With this state, it seems my web can only run one process at a time.

Comment: You can run multiple processes at the same time. Maybe the task that is running is way to "heavy" for the server?

Comment: when u run project with php-fpm - it will be multi process. BTW for this use Laravel Jobs in async mode.

Comment: Use Queue worker with Supervisor, multiple processes , and from the supervisor configuration file you could use the number of processes You will needed.

Comment: Session locks might be the case. What session handler you are using?

Comment: @Constantine i use laravel session.  i just add this to the login controller: 
$request->session()->put('user', ['username' => Auth::user()->username, 'user_role' => Auth::user()->role]);
and then i create a middleware to check the session.

I already tried to remove the session handler in my code, but the web still waiting when there's process in the controller.

Comment: @lely Here is the good article describing session blocks https://ma.ttias.be/php-session-locking-prevent-sessions-blocking-in-requests/
Depending on a driver you are using this might be the case https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#session-blocking

Comment: @Constantine i already tried to use redis for storing session but it keeps locking the process. can i use websocket to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan serve` uses built-in php web server https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Cite from the manual

> The web server runs only one single-threaded process, so PHP applications will stall if a request is blocked.